# Why does the static integer in the class increment?

Tags: objective-c

I am wondering why in the following code the static integer does not stay 0? Is it because in objective-c classes are objects, too and the CoolClass Class is kind of kept around like a singleton?

```
@interface CoolClasss : NSObject
  +(void)staticMethod;
@end

@implementation CoolClass
  static int integer=0;
  +(void)staticMethod {
    NSLog(@"integer: %d", integer);
    integer++;
  }
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    [CoolClass staticMethod];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most OO languages, static variables do not belong to an individual object. That means a single copy of the variable is shared by *all* objects in that class. It also means the variable exists regardless of whether there are any objects in existence for that class.

What's happening here is that you're calling the static method which increments the static variable. No surprises there.

`CoolClass` is *not* a singleton. A singleton is defined as a class that never allows itself to have more then one object.

Here (and in C++ for that matter), you can argue that the static member is *like* a singleton inasmuch as there's only ever one in existence but that is not the true definition of a singleton class, just a side-effect of being shared among objects.

Comment: I was thinking that the integer would of just stayed 0 the whole time. I see, so the class is kept around in memory and is shared with all it's objects. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Obj-C has no concept of class variables (or "members"), so it doesn't make sense to describe them as "belonging to" the class. Static variables in Objective-C work exactly the same way they do in C.

Comment: I don't think a Singleton needs to prevent multiple instantiation. It's common to write a class in a way that allows multiple instances, but tell the IoC container to always inject the same instance. I'd still call that a singleton, even if you could create multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

I woke up and realized I should of checked wikipedia. I was up way too late. I did not understand what it meant to be static and this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) helped add to my new understanding of what it also means to be static globally and locally.

Comment: Think of it as "static" as opposed to "dynamic".  Static variables are allocated by the compiler, not the runtime.